# Plot eigenfunctions w/ looped boundary conditions on a torus

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, finite-element-method, coordinate-transformation

How we can show results (eigenfunctions) obtained in this post on the surface of a torus, not on a square?

https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/differential-eigensystems/investigate-a-laplace-equation-on-a-torus.html?product=mathematica

Comment: Please make your question self-contained by including the necessary code here. First, links will certainly break at some point in the future, and then your question will make no sense. Second, it's more appropriate, when asking for help, to try and minimize the effort required to help you...

Comment: This is a interesting question. But you need to post the code here.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

You should always attempt to post your own solution, even if it does not work at the beginning. But there is a very simple approach, which I'd like to point out. Instead of `Plot3D` one can use 2D functions like `ContourPlot` and texture-map it on torus. Let's solve again:

```
torusBCs={u[0,y]==u[1,y],u[x,0]==u[x,1]};
constraint = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x == 0 && y == 0];
{vals, funs} = NDEigensystem[
   Join[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], constraint}, torusBCs], 
   u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], 4];
```

Then build texture images for all eigenvalues (you have quite a few options to style the texture in the way you want):

```
viz=Rasterize[ContourPlot[#, {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}],
PlotPoints->100,Contours->15,ContourStyle->Opacity[.5],Frame->False,
ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap",PlotRangePadding->0,ImageSize->1000]]&/@funs
```

[image]

Now you can texture-map these on torus:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] (3+Cos[v]),Sin[u] (3+Cos[v]),Sin[v]},{u,0,2 Pi},{v,0,2 Pi},
PlotStyle->Directive[Texture[#]],TextureCoordinateFunction->({#4,#5}&),
Lighting->"Neutral",Mesh->None,Axes->False,SphericalRegion->True]&/@viz
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Vitaliy, Very nice answer: I tried this `torusBCs = {u[0, y, z] == u[1, y, z], u[x, y, 0] == u[x, y, 1], 
   u[x, 0, z] == u[x, 1, z]};
constraint = 
  DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 0, x == 0 && y == 0 && z == 0];
{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[
   Join[{-Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], constraint}, torusBCs], 
   u[x, y, z], {x, y, z} \[Element] Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}], 4];
` and it seems to take forever. Could you please reproduce the pb?

Comment: @chris Does this help `AbsoluteTiming[{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[
   Join[{-Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], constraint}, torusBCs], 
   u[x, y, z], {x, y, z} \[Element] Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}], 4, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" 
-> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}}}]]`?

Comment: @TimLaska a lot! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Rewrite the original code. Here we use `ColorFunction` in `ParametricPlot3D`,and map the rectangle `0<=u<=1,0<=v<=1` to torus by

$$(u,v)\mapsto  (4+(3+\cos (2 \pi  v)) \sin (2 \pi  u),4+(3+\cos (2 \pi  v)) \cos (2 \pi  u),4+\sin (2 \pi  v))$$

Here `4` and `3` can replace to any `R` and `r`.

```
torusBCs = {u[0, y] == u[1, y], u[x, 0] == u[x, 1]};
constraint = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x == 0 && y == 0];
{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[
   Join[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], constraint}, torusBCs], 
   u[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], 4];
Table[ParametricPlot3D[{4 + (3 + Cos[2 π*v]) Sin[2 π*u], 
    4 + (3 + Cos[2 π*v]) Cos[2 π*u], 4 + Sin[2 π*v]}, {u, 
    0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
   ColorFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, 
     ColorData["TemperatureMap"][funs[[i]] /. {x -> u, y -> v}]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> True, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
   ImageSize -> Small], {i, 1, 4}]
```

[image]

Comment: how you found that the torus domain should be as
4 + (3 + Cos[2 π*v]) Sin[2 π*u],4 + (3 + Cos[2 π*v]) Cos[2 π*u], 4 + Sin[2 π*v]?
what is the relation between this and rectangle 0<=u<=1,0<=v<=1?
is there a general formulation between them?

Comment: @imankarimipour  0<=u<=1,0<=v<=1 can map to any torus {f[u,v], 0<=u<=1,0<=v<=1 },here f[u,v]={R + (r + Cos[2 π*v]) Sin[2 π*u], 
 R + (r + Cos[2 π*v]) Cos[2 π*u], R + Sin[2 π*v]}

Comment: what is for example best torus to map for {f[u,v], 0<=u<=2,0<=v<=2}

Comment: @imankarimipour We can replace `2 π` to `π` in the map : {R + (r + Cos[2 πv]) Sin[2 πu], R + (r + Cos[2 πv]) Cos[2 πu], R + Sin[2 π*v]}